# IOS and .plists

Tags: ios, xcode

I am working on an app for a Senior Capstone and I am working with .plist for the first time. What I have so far is in my .h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
-(NSString *)dataFilePath;
-(IBAction) readPlist:(id)sender;
-(IBAction) writePlist:(id)sender;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textBox;

@end
```

and in my .m I have:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
-(NSString *) dataFilePath
{
    NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES );
    NSString *documentDirectory = [path objectAtIndex:0];
    return [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"JoesData.plist"];
}
- (IBAction)readPlist:(id)sender
{
    NSString *filePath = [self dataFilePath];
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath])
    {
        NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
        NSLog(@"%@\n",array);
        NSLog(@"%@\n", filePath);
    }
}
- (IBAction)writePlist:(id)sender {
    NSString *string = _textBox.text;
    NSMutableArray *anArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [anArray addObject:string];
    [anArray writeToFile:[self dataFilePath] atomically:YES];
}
@end
```

so what this does is creates a .plist based upon what is in the text box that I have set up in my storyboard. My problem with this is that it will read and write it just fine, but it won't keep a running list of the things that are entered into the text box. Instead, it simply overwrites the previous .plist. Any thoughts on how to fix the overwriting problem?

Answer (score 1):

Read the plist into memory, make a mutable copy of the array, and add the object to that array, instead of creating a new `NSMutableArray` every time.

Comment: @joeBustamante: `NSMutableArray *ary = [[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[self dataFilePath]] mutableCopy] ?: [NSMutableArray array]; [ary addObject:string]; [ary writeToFile:[self dataFilePath] atomically:YES];`

Answer (score 0):

An alternative option is to do the following.

`To read the property-list data back into your program, first initialize an allocated NSData object by invoking initWithContentsOfFile: or initWithContentsOfURL: or call a corresponding class factory method such as dataWithContentsOfFile:. Then call the propertyListFromData:mutabilityOption:format:errorDescription: class method of NSPropertyListSerialization, passing in the data object.`

[Property List Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/ReadWritePlistData/ReadWritePlistData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i-CH8-SW1)